# How to install a non bundle of Liferay?

Tags: liferay

I want to install a non bundle version of Liferay. Which version should I download and how I should install it? I mean should I download Liferay source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay Sourcecode is not necessary. You just download the "WAR" distribution and the dependencies - those are classes that go to the global classpath of whatever application server you're using.

The documentation for all (or at least many) application servers is here:

- [Version 6.0](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/installing-liferay-for-an-enterpri-4)
- [Version 6.1](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/installing-liferay-on-an-existing-application-server)

You can find the downloads at [www.liferay.com/downloads](https://www.liferay.com/downloads) when you click on "Additional Files page"

Comment: I cant find war distribution in liferay.com. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

May be this one will help to download

http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/initial-setup-4

http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/overview

http://www.liferay.com/